# Need a secure Cross platform gui language

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages, cross-platform, toolkit

It may sound like a lot, but I am looking for a language that is cross platform that I can compile into a single stand alone exe. The source code needs to be secure (Not just hidden) and have some sort of gui toolkit. Do any exist?

Comment: A few things: "exe" is not a cross-platform file type. What do you mean by "secure (Not just hidden)"? What is the "hate" tag?

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I was just using stand alone exe as an example. And by secure I don't want my source to just be embedded and then thrown to an interpreter.

Comment: Was this just tagged "hate," or was I hallucinating?

Comment: @detly: It most certainly was. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, I know 2 cross-platform UI toolkits: [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) and [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org).

Comment: QT is abbreviation for QuickTime. Cross-platform application and UI framework is called Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a language with more GUI toolkits or that is more cross-platform than [the C programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)).

Answer (score 0):

In python here is the list  [cross platform gui](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

For Java you can use [Swings](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial) and [AWT](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/awt/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your source secure is a problem - how do you define secure and why do you think you need it like this?

Cross plattform with only one compilation - hits only on .NET/mono and Java, both not interpreted, but work with a intermediate compilation of some sort of VM. Code can be relatively easy decompiled, though it can be obfuscated.

Cross plattform with compilation for every plattform is far easier, with C, C++ and many many more your have a great choice. You could then watch out for your GUI-Toolkit of choice and check the languages that have bindings for it.

Answer (score 0):

I use REAL Studio (formally REALbasic) for creating standalone cross-platform applications.  The apps are also compiled and fully native, so it sounds like they would meet your definition of secure.

And REAL Studio is a *lot* easier to start with Qt (unless you already happen to be a C++ expert).